# Intermediate mail server or how to get IMAP with POP

Tags: imap, pop3, gmail-imap

I have the following problem: my university mail is on a IMAP server and I'm a Gmail user. I want to forward my university mail to mail Gmail, but it only accepts POP3 servers. I'm wondering if there is an online service on the internet that transforms IMAP mail to POP mail?

Comment: You want to *fetch* mail from the IMAP server. Can't you set up actual  (active) *forwarding* from your university mail service? Most of them should allow permanent forwarding.

Comment: In theory I can, but the thing doesn't work. They seem to be having problems for a while now and I figured I should do something about it myself.